# PC hangs badly with ubuntu 10.04 64-bit version

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04

My PC Configuration is following
- intel core-i3 proseccer
 
- 2 GB RAM
- Working with Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit version
It hangs badly, even its very hard to move cursor.

Why it hangs? and 
What should i update in my system?

Please help me..

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the 10.04 version?  I'd try the 12.04 LTS or 13.04 version as they have newer kernels and might address hardware incompatibilities you're experiencing.

Comment: Yes.. i have to use ubuntu 10.04 64 bit as i am working with android custom build, they allowing higher version but their recommended version is 10.04 thats only the reason